# Turn off mobile data for some specific apps

Tags: android

I want to off mobile data for some specific apps,what I want is that if my mobile data is on then I can allow only whatsapp to access,no other app. I know its possible because some apps for same are available on google play but I am not getting any code for the same. I have googled a lot.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: tell me in single line...what is your first requirement ?

Comment: @RohitGoswami- i just want to turn off mobile data for some specific apps.

Comment: did u got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Data usage  then you can see app usage and select each app and turn on restrict app background data.

Comment: I want it through some code thats why I m asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a VPN application. Within the application you can make a list which apps allowed to access internet and which apps not to allow it. Make sure the connection is through that VPN application. Then filter the connection in your VPN based on the lists

Comment: can u plz provide me some link as its new for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPN, build your own server and transmit all the traffic through that server, than you can filter all the traffic.
Maybe you can google "OpenVpn" or "ToyVPN" in android's sdk for some ref.

Comment: Yes, but you need to allow VPN app in setting because of Android's policy.